# VMWARE Workstation player 14 on WIN10 with Ubuntu 18.04 on 4K display fixing DPI scaling

Tags: display, vmware, hdpi

I would like to learn more about linux, so I downloaded ubuntu iso, booted it up in vmware.

However I cannot find any way to force DPI scaling, there is no option under display settings other than trying to change the actual resolution.

I have tried multiple fixes such as compatability modes, and these:

```
xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 1.25x1.25

gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"
```

which I found in other stackexchange posts.

Neither of them worked for me.

---

Is there any other solution? I am on a Dell XPS 15 9560 4K 15.6 inch laptop, making ubuntu unusable without x2 - x2.5 scaling.

---

Output of running xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 1 x 1, current 3840 x 1919, maximum 8192 x 8192
Virtual1 connected primary 3840x1919+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   3840x1919     60.00*+
   2560x1600     59.99  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.00  
   1792x1344     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x768      59.87  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
Virtual2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual6 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual7 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
Virtual8 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: What output do you get from running `xrandr --output eDP1 --scale 1.25x1.25`? This command should do what you want (maybe with a higher scale factor), but in a VM your output might be named differently. To find all available outputs, run `xrandr` without arguments.

Comment: it literally did nothing, the screen flashed that's it. I am extremely new to linux and have never used it before, does xrandr run on the bare ubuntu install or does it require anything?

Comment: It requires a running X-Server (thats what is driving your graphical user interface, so I assume you have one) and if the screen flashes, it probably works. Please provide the output of `xrandr` without any arguments in your question (edit it).

Comment: do I have to login with gnome?

Comment: it says output eDP1 not found

Comment: I suspected that. Please run just `xrandr` without any arguments, edit your question and copy paste the output in your question. That is the inforamtion necessary to construct the command you need.

Comment: added to original post

Comment: Try running `xrandr --output Virtual1 --scale 2x2`.

Comment: That made the display even smaller, I ran 0.5x0.5 and that made it correct size. Thank you though, if you want to leave it as an answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xrandr` command you already found uses the wrong output, eDP1, which is normally a notebook display. In your `xrandr` output you see a line

```
Virtual1 connected primary 3840x1919+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
```

The first word in that line (`Virtual1`) is the output name, so using that in the command should work:

`xrandr --output Virtual1 --scale 0.5x0.5`

Please be aware that this is not a persistent setting, so after reboot you have to enter the command again. I'm not using gnome, so I can't tell you if you can set this somewhere in gnome settings. I myself have a monitor setup at work with different DPI and use a similar xrandr command and have made a key binding so I can press a key after connecting the screens.

Comment: Thank you, yea I will use it every time, maybe I'll write a script to automate it upon login.